# How to remove item from array if repeated more than specific quantity in PHP?

Tags: php

I would like to remove item from PHP array if repeated more than specific quantity. For example.

```
$org_array = ["dog","cat","dog","cat","elephant","dog","bird","bird","frog","bird","frog","bird"]
```

if repeat = 4, so bird is removed.

```
$array4repeat = ["dog","cat","dog","cat","elephant","dog","frog","frog"]
```

if repeat = 3, then bird and dog are removed.

```
$array4repeat = ["cat","cat","elephant","frog","frog"]
```

Any advice or guidance on this would be greatly appreciated, Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Count occurrences of each value (e.g. using [array_count_values](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php))
2. Either create new array, to where only allowed values are copied; or modify the source array removing unwanted items.

```
<?php
  $org_array = ["dog","cat","dog","cat","elephant","dog","bird","bird","frog","bird","frog","bird"];

  $val_count = array_count_values($org_array);

  $repeat = 4;

  $array4repeat = array();

  foreach($org_array as $v) {
    if ($val_count[$v] < $repeat) $array4repeat[] = $v;
  }

  print_r($array4repeat);
```

prints

```
Array
(
    [0] => dog
    [1] => cat
    [2] => dog
    [3] => cat
    [4] => elephant
    [5] => dog
    [6] => frog
    [7] => frog
)
```